# Set the colour of all the labels in tableview

Tags: swift, tableview, sections

How would I set the colour of each label in table view section using swift?

I have done this but it does not work.

Thanks

```
    for section in 0..<tableView.numberOfSections {
        for row in 0..<tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) {
            let indexPath = NSIndexPath(row: row, section: section)
            var cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

            if (cell as? UILabel) != nil {
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .red

            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: why you want to do that ?

Comment: Are the cells always supposed to be red, or do they become red based on some other action?

Comment: Could you show us your tableview delegate? Cells are created/recycled/customised in the delegate.

Comment: This cannot work because a cell cannot be cast to `UILabel`. Manipulating the cells directly (even the invisible ones) is bad practice anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You should be set the cell's properties inside the `cellForRowAt` method, like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: <#T##String#>, for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.backgroundColor = .red
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making a conflict with type. 
In this line you are assigning the cell type to variable cell

```
var cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
```

And In this line of code you are asking if cell is a UILabel then make it text label colour to red.

This will always return false and code inside if will never execute.

```
            if (cell as? UILabel) != nil {
                cell?.textLabel?.textColor = .red

            }
```

Remove the if statement and then execute the code.